# Equation System help (Isolating)

Tags: systems-of-equations

I've been stuck trying to isolate the variables "x" and "y" in this equation system and was wondering if any one here has the time to solve this for me.

```
y = rotatedPointY - pointX * s - pointY * c + y * c + x * s
x = rotatedPointX - pointX * c + pointY * s - y * s + x * c
```

The closest I've got is this but as you can see it pretty far off and might be incorrect.

```
y = (rotatedPointY - pointX * s - pointY * c + (x * s)) / (1 - c))
x = rotatedPointX - pointX * c + pointY * s - y * s + x * c 
---
y = rotatedPointY / (1 - c) - (pointX * s) / (1 - c) - (pointY * c) / (1 - c) + (x * s) / (1 - c)
---
x = rotatedPointX - pointX * c + pointY * s - (rotatedPointY / (1 - c) - (pointX * s) / (1 - c) - (pointY * c) / (1 - c) + (x * s) / (1 - c)) * s + x * c
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You've probably done roughly the right thing (I haven't followed through all of the logic), but you can make things a lot easier on yourself by replacing all the terms that don't involve $x$ or $y$ with single values, e.g. set $A = $ `rotatedPointY - pointX * s - pointY * c`, so your equations reduce to forms like $y = A + cy + sx$ and $x = B - sy + cx$, then the algebra will look much simpler.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.